# Android: Using <include/> to clone layouts, while using the same onClick button functions

Tags: android, layout, include

I want to use an "actionbar", like tapatalk has.
Ofcourse I don't want to copy all button functions over and over again.

Is there a quick solution to do this?

Also, if I set the background drawable, I want it to be the same in the different layouts.

Comment: Do you want all the buttons to behave the same way? How about extending activity with one that has the onClick already implemented? In that case you'll need to be sure that the layout includes your common layout

Comment: Wow that's a smart one! And what about the background drawables? Will they appear the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two approaches:

- As I said in the comment, make all your activities extend a base activity of yours that implements the onClick. Mayebe I don't like this approach because it forces you to extend your base activity and if you want a listactivity in the future you may have some problems.

or (which I think it's much better)

- simply have an helper class that accepts the activity as a constructor argument which will set the onclicks for you. You'll have to remember to instantiate that class (or call a static method if you are worried about creating objects), and that will do the job for you.

  ```
  public class OnClickHelper implements View.OnClickListener {
     Activity mActivity;
     public OnClickHelper(Activity a){
         mActivity = a;
     }   


     public setClickListeners(){
         Button b = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
         b.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
           case R.id.button1:

           break;
        }
     }
  ```

  }

Regarding the background, go for styles. Have all the activities you want to have the same background using the same style (you can define it in the manifest).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me :) But I'm afraid the way I wanted to do this isn't right. I'm posting my edited question right now.